# http error while uploading video to youtube with php

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a video to youtube using php and api version 3.

Everything is done correctly yet I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet:
>   (403) Forbidden' in C:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\Google\Http\REST.php:79
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\Google\Http\REST.php(44):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\Google\Client.php(499):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\Google\Service\Resource.php(195):
>   Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\Google\Service\YouTube.php(3116):
>   Google_Service_Resource->call('insert', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\upload.php(60): Google_Service_YouTube_Videos_Resource->insert('status,snippet',
>   Object(Google_Service_YouTube_Video), Array) #5 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\Google\Http\REST.php on line 79

This is where I upload the video

```
if($client->getAccessToken()) {

$snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle("Test title2");
$snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
$snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
$snippet->setCategoryId("22");

$status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "private";

$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);

$videoData = file_get_contents("out.mp4");
$youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video, array("data" => $videoData, "mimeType" => "out.mp4"));


}
```

Comment: "Everything is done correctly" - Um, no. If it was correct, you wouldn't get an error. Where is your code?

Comment: @relentless you are right lol I'll add the part where I upload the video.

Comment: Most likely missing/wrong auth token.

Comment: @this.lau_ not really, the authentication went well

Comment: Yes, the authentication went well. You're now authenticated. Thanks to that authentication (that went well), the server-system can respond with 403 Forbidden because that authenticated user is forbidden to POST to that endpoint. Anything else you'd like to ask about?